# Не создается класс в IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Здравствуйте . Установил идею и возникла проблема не могу создать класс никакой - выходит сообщение - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем может быть ошибка ? Так вроде все работает

Comment: гляньте [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45497266/unable-to-parse-template-class)

Comment: thank you very match . )